# Heroku - Python / Django R14 - Memory quota exceeded

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I am unable to delete model instances in the Django admin.  When I try I get an application error with the following logs:

```
2017-06-01T16:49:52.582763+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-01 16:49:52 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:27)
2017-06-01T16:49:53.966027+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-01 16:49:53 +0000] [54] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54
2017-06-01T16:50:12.048171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=642M(125.4%)
2017-06-01T16:50:12.048339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-06-01T16:50:22.371199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/admin/auth/user/" request_id=e850ec27-3452-4e05-9077-00107a6dbd08 fwd="69.250.203.83" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2017-06-01T16:50:23.409859+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-01 16:50:23 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:45)
2017-06-01T16:50:23.676154+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-01 12:50:23 +0000] [45] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 45)
2017-06-01T16:50:24.927345+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-01 16:50:24 +0000] [63] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63
```

This is my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn djangoall.wsgi
worker: celery -A djangoall worker --autoscale=10,3
beat: celery -A djangoall beat -S django
```

Performing this action works fine in my local environment. The Heroku documentation references memory errors are language specific and does not include a Python guide.

I have looked at the number of SO questions but did not have success when I lowered workers by one (by changing --autoscale=10,3 to --autoscale=10,2) per this answer [I am getting Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) in heroku with a Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149831/i-am-getting-error-r14-memory-quota-exceeded-in-heroku-with-a-django-app).

Comment: Can you elaborate "I am unable to delete model instances in the Django admin."? How are you attempting this deletion?

Comment: I am in the users section of my admin (/admin/auth/user/). I am clicking the checkbox next to a user then going to the dropdown labeled action at the top and selecting "delete selected users" then go. After clicking go, the app spends 20-30 seconds loading before taking me to an application error page.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question, you are trying to delete model instances from your app's admin panel. Let's assume you achieve that with no memory-quota errors from Heroku, that would free up database storage space.

The error you're getting has to do with your traffic. Try spinning up another web dyno, as this is running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku restart` solved this for me.