# Heroku memory quota exceeded after build succeeded

Tags: heroku

My app in heroku build succeeded but crashed after causing memory limit exceeded.
Anyone come across this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ceLm.png)

Comment: May be this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149831/i-am-getting-error-r14-memory-quota-exceeded-in-heroku-with-a-django-app

Answer (score 0):

Your application requires more memory than we Heroku allocates for the Free Tier Dynos. You need to tune/decrease the memory footprint (what to do it depends on which language you use and libraries).